# How to read specific columns from Cassandra table using Datastax spark-cassandra-connector?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-cassandra-connector_2.11 (version 2.0.5) to load data from Cassandra into Spark cluster. I am using read api to load the data as follows :

```
SparkUtil.initSpark()
         .read
         .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
         .options(Map("table"-><table_name>, "keyspace"-><keyspace>))
         .load()
```

Its working fine, however, in one of the use case I want to read only a specific column from Cassandra. How to use read api to do the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SparkUtil.initSpark()
         .read
         .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
         .options(Map("table"-><table_name>, "keyspace"-><keyspace>))
         .load()
         .select("column_name")
```

Use `select`.. you can also use case classes

Answer (score 3):

Other way is to use following approach without using options api.

```
SparkUtil.initSpark()
         .sparkContext
         .cassandraTable(<keyspace>, <table_name>) 
         .select(<column_name>)
```

Answer (score -1):

One line solution for fetching few columns from Cassandra table :

val rdd=sc.cassandraTable("keyspace","table_name")
   .select("service_date","mobile").persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)